# divs next to eachother, float:left or right will not work

Tags: css

http://earldev.tumblr.com/

I am making a theme that uses a script that lets the `div` scroll on mouseover. The images work find but any text posts will float below the other text post. I tried `float:left`,  `float:right`, `clear:right`, `clear:both`, `display:inline`, pretty much anything. Help?

Comment: An extract of your code would help. It's hard to figure out what's wrong otherwise.

Comment: well you see on my page how it scrolls on mouseover? go to the very end of the div and you will see 3-4 text posts. they are each ontop of the other and im trying to get them to go side by side.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a width to the divs and then float it to any of the sides, if you don't specify a width, the it will take the whole 100% of the size, thus sending the next one to the bottom!

Hope I can help!

Comment: thanks for replying! i already did. if you look at the source of the page i provided, the text posts (below photo posts) are width:380 (i think?) and they are in the scrolling div which is set to 100%. posts have float:left; and seem to ahve the problem still.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a CSS issue, you have your elements nested incorrectly. For the text entries, you're closing the divs of class `textt` but not the divs of class `posts`, so the second text entry is in the first, and the third is in the second.

Comment: i think that might work! thankyou, please note im only 16 and i just like to make themes so im not very sharp on my code :)

Comment: No sweat, I wish the Web existed when I was 16 :)

Comment: also, i saved it onto the page so you can see what i mean.

Comment: could it be that the overflow div is not large enough? i mean, i have it set to 5000px im pretty sure that would hold a couple of 280px divs and some pictures...

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying is wrong now, as entries appear to be next to each other whether they're images or text. Note however that your images are in an li element of their own, but the text entries are all in a single li. Using a debugging tool such as Firebug might be useful for you.

Comment: if you go to my page, go to the end of the div (move mouse to right) and look at "i need this 24/7" that is a seperate post, a seperate div that shouldnt be under the one above it.

Comment: woah, well it turns out you are an html genius! i needed each post to have its own list style. thanks!